# Java Class/Design, inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I need your advice. I have two classes: OV and POV. POV includes some methods from OV but may be extended in the future. I want to implement an abstract class to make the design of my classes more understandable and remove redundant code. I thought up two possible solutions:

1. OV class extends PO class and  NewAbstractClass extends OV class. I put all general methods (for OV and PO) in the NewAbstract class.
2. NewAbstractClass extends OV and I extend PO from the NewAbstract class.

What solution is the best? Maybe someone would suggest something else! THANKS!

Comment: In 1. do you mean: PO extends OV and OV extends AbstractClass?

Comment: You should create proper names for your classes like `Mammal`, `Fish`, `Cat`... or something like that to make the class hierarchy understandable

Comment: Names of the classes present here as  example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a true IS-A relationship between OV and POV?

That is, is POV a special type of OV, and wherever you have an OV you could also use a POV? If so POV can extend OV.

Alternatively, if they do not have an IS-A relationship, but happen to use some similar methods, you could create a class to implement those common methods and encapsulate an instance inside both POV and OV, delegating to the encapsulated instance, but not exposing it in POV or OV's interface. In this way you avoid duplicating code, but don't introduce a relationship between your classes which doesn't really exist.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution!